# Code that once worked, no longer works? Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to test build this old 'text adventure' thing I found,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////// VARIABLES //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
string name;
string shipName;

int health;
int crewCount;
int armyTotal, activeArmy;
int casualtiesCount, woundedCount, healedCount;

// 'food' as in a whole meal (beverage, chewables, etc)
int foodCount;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// INTRODUCTIONS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
cout << "What is thy name?\nName: ";
cin >> name;
cout << endl << "What will you name your ship?\nShip Name: ";
cin >> shipName;

cout << "\nSETTING: You are floating through space on giant space cruiser " << endl << "known as the " << shipName << ".\n You are on a random patrol sorti, just looking out for any trouble...";
cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
cin.get();

cout << "\nFrom here on out, type corresponding number to which choice you want to make.\nPress ENTER to continue...";
cin.get();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////// BEGINNING ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cout << endl << "Admiral " << name << ", we need you on flight deck.";
cout << "1: Go to flight deck.";
cout << "2: Go to kitchen.";
cout << "3: Go to MedBay.";
cout << "4: Do nothing.";
```

}

and I get an error for:

```
cin >> name;
```

where ">>"  matches no operands. 
I clearly remember this code working at some point I do believe. If I try and skip ahead, I get an error where it can't find an exe (and there is no option to Build Final)

Sorry for not being clear, but I haven't used C++ for a few years now, quite rusty on just about everything. Any sort of wisdom to shed?

Comment: Start a new empty visual studio 2010 project, copy paste the code in and then try. MSVS is sometimes a bit weird with old versions. Also please use `std::cin` etc. `using namespace std` makes it very easy to produce 'invisible' bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include <string>`. That's where the actual operator is defined. Chances are that in the past, `<iostream>` may have included it perchance, which it's allowed to but not required (or guaranteed) to.

Comment: Aha, this fixed everything! Thank you!